# Running Go as a daemon webserver on CentOS 7

Tags: go

I am trying to migrate from PHP to Go and planning to drop nginx alltogether. But I don't know how to run the go http webserver as a deamon in the background and I also don't know how to automatically start the webserver if I make a reboot, or how to kill the process.

With nginx all I do is

```
$ systemctl start nginx.service
$ systemctl restart nginx.service
$ systemctl stop nginx.service
$ systemctl enable nginx.service
$ systemctl disable nginx.service
```

This is very convenient, but it seems like I can't do this with Go http server. I have to compile and run it as any other Go program. What solutions do exist for these concerns?

Comment: Writing a systemd unit file is going to (relatively) straightforward and give you a familar interface. As touched on by @Verran, you could also use [Supervisor](http://elithrar.github.io/article/running-go-applications-in-the-background/) (I wrote a blog post on how to set it up for a Go binary) as well; plus all of the other options like monit/runit/Upstart, etc.

Comment: Cool. I'd like to read that blog post, what is the url?

Comment: Click the word Supervisor in my first comment (StackOverflow doesn't make links obvious!)

Comment: for some reason I can't run as deamon with supervisord unless it is with root. Do you know anything about that elithrar?

Comment: Your Go application shouldn't need root. Supervisor should not but it will depend if your Go app is trying to bind to port 80—which requires root or the capability to do so. If that's what you're trying to do, `setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /path/to/your/go/binary` will provide that. If you're still having issues raise a fresh question with your error messages under the [supervisor] tag here on SO.

Comment: It worked, I want to donate for the help. Been trying for the whole day..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is less of a Go question and more of a Systems Administration question. There are ways to add a command to systemd (like in [this blog post](https://scottlinux.com/2014/12/08/how-to-create-a-systemd-service-in-linux-centos-7/)).

Personally, I prefer to keep my applications separate from my services, so I tend to use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) for my programs that tend to be started, stopped, or restarted frequently. The documentation for supervisord is pretty straightforward, but essentially you can create a config file to describe the services you want to run, the command used to run it (such as `/path/to/go/binary -flag`) how you want to handle starting, stopping, failure recovery, logging, etc....